# How to pass the gaction token to gactions when it is called by an exec node (without operator)

Tags: google-apps-script, command-line-interface, actions-on-google, node-red

Impossible to pass the token, because I have no possibility to paste any code.
The command gaction cli is made by the application.
When gactions is launched, it replies with an URL, to access to the account, and get the token.
But as this gactions is started by the code itself (inside `node-red`, an exec node), I haven't the possibility to paste the token returned by google.
So, is there any other method to register the `action.json` file to the app?

I already tried to paste the token to the same exec node of nodered, but unsuccessfully, because the PID changes each time a new command is passed.

I already tried to paste the token using a deamon node, also unsuccessfully (error)

Here is how my gaction file is called:

```
gactions test -preview_mins 9999999 -action_package action.json -project my-test-app-11111
```

Actually, the node-red node returns the URL which has to be pasted in a browser.
Then I must identify at my account in Google actions web site, and then, I get a token.

What I need know is the possibility to start gactions with the parameters and the token in the same command line, or to ask gactions (used on Linux) to register by itself with my identification logins.

Answer (score 0):

On a client, when you log into gactions, it will create a `creds.data` file in that directory, which contains information about your login credentials to automatically authenticate later. If this file is not found, you will be asked to authenticate to get these credentials. If your system has the `creds.data` file located in the same directory, you should be able to run commands without the explicit need to login each time.

Comment: The problem is that the file creds.data seems to be accessible when gactions is started in the terminal. but when I start gactions, with the same parameters, gactions seems to not see this file creds.data, even if it is really there, and available for the actual user, with the corrects rights.  When I start gaction with --verbose,I see all the responses. And I have discovered that the same command, used in the terminal and started by node-red doesn't return exactly the same thing. Details here : https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-enter-a-line-after-an-exec-node-is-started/12442/9

Comment: I don't know a lot about node-red, but are you sure that there's not some file issues happening where it can't see the file or executes in a different directory where the file does not exist?

Comment: Yes, i am suer (as much as i can), because gactions is in the same directory than creds.data. and the rights are the same (gactions has x activated because it is an executable, of course)

Comment: Hi @NickFelker how can we generate creds.data file ? I am getting this error https://ibb.co/hVpnCPX